# ngCordovaOauth + Firebase google auth not working

Tags: firebase, google-oauth, firebase-authentication, ngcordova

I have created an Ionic app which uses Firebase Authentication. I'm trying to authenticate using Google. This is a part of my code trying to achieve the same.

```
$cordovaOauth.google("//removed_client_id", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]).then(function (result) {
    var credentials = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(result.id_token);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(credentials));
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials).then(function (authData) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(authData));
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm not getting any results in 'authData' as fields like displayName, photoUrl, email are null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you actually getting a user returned? is there a uid and providerData array in the authData object? The google data should be in there. It is also possible you are using "Multiple accounts per email" in your Firebase console settings. In that case the top level email will be null. More information would be helpful here.

Comment: I'm getting the uid and provider as well. But the uid seems to be different each time for reasons unknown. And all the other fields are null. Another thing to note is this works when I'm signing in with the google account associated with my firebase app and not for any other google account. May be some permission issue?